# Layout positioning issue: a not required action header div should influence the position of the scrollable content div

Tags: css, position, css-position

Okay there are 2 scenarios:

I have a layout like this:

```
----------------
button header
----------------
Contents
Contents
Contents
Contents (with scrollbar)
Contents
------------
footer
------------
```

What I want to achieve is:
The buttonheader and footer must always stay in view - the content must be scrollable.
**The buttonheader can be empty - thus the scrollable content should move above the 
buttonheader - there is no point in losing space if there is no buttons**.

So absolute/fixed positioning seems to not be an option so I tried with relative. (The reason absolute is no solution, is because if the contents are placed absolutely there, they will never move in case the buttonheader is empty.)

I set the height to percentage - but It will of course look very bad in case someone resizes the window.

Look here and resize the outputwindow:

[sad attempt on how to get a working relative positioned scrollable content](http://jsfiddle.net/6HbSN/)

The second version:

[is to show what it should behave like (at the top part) - content should stick to top of the page - footer is wrong here](http://jsfiddle.net/6HbSN/2/)

Comment: Can the header be gone, or only be empty (but still exist)? Are you looking for a HTML/CSS solution or is script allowed?

Comment: @WillemVanBockstal the header can exist but it will be empty. Only css is allowed actually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flexible behavior sounded a lot like that of a table-row, so I went that way in CSS. 
Added a few extra div's to make firefox play nicely inside the main cell.

See http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/XMEcC/

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

#header, #footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: table-row;
}

#main{
   height: 100%;
   display: table-row;    
}

#cell{
   display: table-cell;    
}

#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}

#overflow{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Edit: only tested in FF and Safari

Comment: works flawlessly in chrome 22.0.1229.94 m as well. I cannot test IE 9 - gotta do that from home. But seems like a nice solution